# Handling AntiForgery.Validate(String, String)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I am using `AntiForgery.Validate(str, str)`  in an ASP.Net MVC application. But I can not understand what this method will return if validation fails.

Here is the code that I am using in my application-

```
        string cookieToken = "";
        string formToken = "";

        IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders = 
        Request.Headers.GetValues("RequestVerificationToken");
        string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
        if (tokens.Length == 2)
        {
            cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
            formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
        }

        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
```

I read [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj158363%28v=vs.111%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in msdn. But not found any useful information that can show me the way out.

How can I handle if `AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken)` fails?

Sorry if this is a foolish question.

Comment: It throws exceptions if its fails (the specific exception depends on various factors). Its not clear what you what to handle, bit you can inspect relevant parts of the source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiForgery.cs), [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/AntiForgeryWorker.cs) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/TokenValidator.cs)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for the reply. What type of exception does it throw?

Comment: Read the bit in parenthesis :) And look at the `ValidateTokens()` method in the 3rd link

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think I found it- HttpAntiForgeryException. Thank you.